# WPF DataGrid: handling CanUserAddRows=true cleanly with MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, caliburn.micro

I've been looking into MVVM lately, and after I discovered [Caliburn.Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/) things have been pretty swell; I'm still in the early learning stages, but I belive I have an OK feel for the MVVM basics.

I'm bumping into issues with WPF `DataGrid`, though - and it's pretty much the [same issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3607468/430360) that I had with WinForms `DataGridView`: how the heck do you handle `CanUserAddRows=true` in-grid item adding cleanly?

I obviously don't want to add `DataGrid`-specific hacks to my ViewModel, since it *ideally* should be repurposable for other `View` controls. At the same time, I'd like to be able to get a notification when a new <strike>row</strike> item has been added, so I can persist it right away.

I'm binding the `DataGrid` to a `BindableCollection<FooModel> FooItems` - with a clean MVVM design, if I understand things correctly, I would be able to handle `FooItems.CollectionChanged` and react to Add/Remove events. However, the `DataGrid` fires the Add event as soon as a default-constructed item is added - this is obviously **not** the right time to persist the object!

After a lot of googling and digging through StackOverflow, I'm getting the impression that `DataGrid` is being utterly retarded in how it's firing the Add/Remove events. People who use it with `CanUserAddRows=true` seem to only work on in-memory collections, where people who persist data seem to use separate input fields + <strike>buttons</strike> Commands to add new items.

My `FooModel` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` but not `IEditableObject` - as far as I can tell that shouldn't be the problem, though, since IEO seems related to property edit/undo, whereas my problem is with when the Add event is fired...

So, what do you do to handle in-grid editing **cleanly**?

Comment: Another option is to have FooModel implement IEditableObject. The DataGrid will call IEditableObject.EndEdit() when the edit operation on the new item is completed (for example the user hits enter). You can then raise an event on FooModel such as EditCommitted. The handler for this event can properly persist new FooModel instances, or update existing ones.

Comment: @eulerfx: thanks - for some reason I had ruled out IEO, but I can't remember why; probably ran into some issues with it on an earlier project. I'll look into again :)

Comment: IMO there is no clean way to implement CanUserAddRows=True in a DataGrid.  We've moved to separate input fields like you mentioned or custom .ShowDialog editing Windows.  Batch saves doesn't fit our design.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the WPF `DataGrid` behaves in much the same way as the WinForms `DataGridView`, in that it creates an item in the data source as soon as the user begins entering into the 'new row'. Subsequent edits would result in changes to the properties of the new item in the collection.

If you were to use `BindingList<FooModel>` instead, you get the additional event called `ListChanged` - providing your `FooModel` type implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, the event will fire when the properties of the item are changed (as well as when items are added/removed from the collection).

Hope this helps!

Comment: P.S. If you are using a persisted data source, wouldn't it make more sense to wait until the user finishes adding/editing all the rows, and then perform a single transacted update to the data source? Real-time updates to persisted data seem wasteful...

Comment: Yep, they behave equally as far as I can tell - IMHO it's pretty retarded behavior. BindingList doesn't help much, unfortunately... and it's ItemRemoved is almost useless since you get the index of the *already* removed item >_<

Comment: And yeah, normally it's saner to batch-commit changes, it just doesn't fit that naturally in the system I'm doing. Binding against a DataTable and being able to Accept/RejectChanges is probably what you should be using with a DataGrid :)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a long time since this was asked but I'm working on something similar now and thought I'd post my solution.  You may consider this a hack but it's the best way I could figure to get DataGrid to tell me when it was out of edit mode (for my own reasons).

I looked through the DataGrid code and found the closest thing to end edit I could override, which turns out to be OnExecutedCommitEdit().  I then just raise an event after that function finishes.  When my event subscriber gets called DataGrid is no longer in edit mode and I can do whatever I need to it.  Here's the code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Deriving a new DataGrid because we need an event to tell us when editing is complete.
/// </summary>
public class DataGridMod : DataGrid
{
   public delegate void EditCompletedDelegate();
   public EditCompletedDelegate EditCompleted;

   public DataGridMod() { }

   protected override void OnExecutedCommitEdit(ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
   {
      base.OnExecutedCommitEdit(e);

      if (EditCompleted != null)
         EditCompleted();
   }
}
```